# Sass::SyntaxError on a basic style (RoR Project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project, sass, syntax-error

I am pretty experienced frontend developer and recently I got a project to make a UI for a ruby on rails project, it uses sass, I am not at all strange to sass, but I get a really weird error.

ABSOLUTELY whatever I input in the projects SASS file it throws an error, here is a screenshot http://screencast.com/t/MxdHmL9O5o

when empty the file is compiled into a application.css, but I am completely clueless about what could be awry here.

If you need more details please feel free to ask.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What I wanted to add is that I am completely clueless about ruby on rails projects too :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SCSS format, defined by using brackets in your CSS in favor of whitespace indentation, you should be using the `.css.scss` extension, **not** the `.css.sass` extension.

From the [Sass homepage](http://sass-lang.com/):

> Sass has two syntaxes. The most commonly used syntax is known as **“SCSS” (for “Sassy CSS”), and is a superset of CSS3’s syntax**. This means that every valid CSS3 stylesheet is valid SCSS as well. **SCSS files use the extension .scss**.
>
> **The second, older syntax is known as the indented syntax (or just “.sass”).** Inspired by Haml’s terseness, it’s intended for people who prefer conciseness over similarity to CSS. **Instead of brackets and semicolons, it uses the indentation of lines to specify blocks.** Files in the indented syntax use the extension .sass.